# Spring: how to use @PropertySource to import resource files which are not in classpath?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In many documents, the usage is @PropertySource is usually like:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/document.properties")
```

In my **Spring-boot** project,  I have the following in `application.properties`

```
config.path=/home/myservice/config.properties
```

and in java source:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"${config.path}"}, encoding="utf-8")
public class MyConfig {
    @Value("${myconfig.index}")
    private String index;

    public String getIndex() {
       return index;
    }
```

}

But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [home/myservice/config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

it seems to me that  @PropertySource import resource files in classpath by default, so my question is how to use @PropertySource to import resource files which are not in classpath?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:@PropertySource(value = {"file:${config.path}"}, encoding="utf-8")

> [Indicate the resource location(s) of the properties file to be loaded. For example, "classpath:/com/myco/app.properties" or "file:/path/to/file".](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can cascade the `PropertySources` to provide fallback/default value.

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/document.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value ="file:/conf/document.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
})
public class MyConfig {

...}
```

Comment: the second @PropertySource is the default while the first is the fallback? how about it if there are three items?

Comment: You can add more PropertySource as needed. They will be loaded in order. Can't remember the sequence and I am not able to try right now (being away from PC)

Comment: it seems to me it is not in order, at least for the case you wrote in the answer, the `file:` is before the `classpath:`